# Django - setting a user to not active for 5 seconds

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my Django project, I allow users to login. If they enter the incorrect password 7 times, their account is set to not active and an error is returned to them.

What I want to do is display the error message for 5 seconds, then allow them to attempt again. How can I do this ?

I store a variable in the user model which is incremented each time a an unsuccessful login is performed. If it reaches 7, an error message is displayed.

Here's my code:
models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    loginAttempts = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py:

```
if user.check_password(data.get("password")):
        user.loginAttempts = 0
        user.save()
        auth.login(request, user)
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Successfully logged in'}, status=200)
else:
        user.loginAttempts += 1
        user.save()
        if user.loginAttempts >= 7:
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Account Locked.'}, status=400)
        else: 
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Oops, username/email or password provided is invalid'}, status=400)
```

Currently the error message **("Account Locked")** is successfully displayed after 7 attempts, however what I want is the **loginAttempts** variable to be set back to 0 after 5 seconds has passed.

How can I do this? Thank You.

Comment: Typically, I'd want to consider doing this on the front end. On the back end, I'd be thinking about something like "set account to inactive and make them request a reset email to continue".

Comment: @JonKiparsky Ah ok. If I were to implement the functionality on the backend, how could I do this. Could I say the python timestamp module to simulate 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add an additional field to the User object named somethign like lastLoginTry. Then you could check if the last try is more than 5 seconds ago.

EDIT:
it is not recommended to inform someone when he tries to log into his account that his account got freezed for some time, because if someone wants to hack an account by just trying some e-mail addresses from which he even doesn't know if an account with this email address exists he will get to know after getting this response. SO just stay at "ooops, user/password is invalid" and tell the user before that their account will get locked after a specified amount of login attempts.

```py
import time
if user.check_password(data.get("password")):
        user.loginAttempts = 0
        user.save()
        auth.login(request, user)
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Successfully logged in'}, status=200)
else:
        user.loginAttempts += 1
        if user.loginAttempts >= 7:
            if time.time() - user.lastFailedLogin >= 5:
                user.is_active = True
                user.loginAttempts = 0
            else:
                user.is_active = False
                user.lastFailedLogin = time.time()
        user.save()
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Oops, username/email or password provided is invalid'}, status=400)
```

i dont have much time to check it now. If someone finds some bugs or so, feel free to edit my answer!!

Comment: As an addendum to this answer, here's an article that might be helpful: https://medium.com/@adriennedomingus/locking-users-out-after-invalid-login-attempts-django-a-cache-75cf5988f56c

Comment: @Sofian Ah nice solution. When implementing this, how would I check if the last try was more than 5 seconds ago? What would the code look like? Thank You.

Comment: @manny Thank you for the solution, however the implementation is different to mine, therefore I don't have access to some of the functions used.

Comment: @Sofian Would I use the timestamp method in python, and if so what would it look like in code. Thank you.

Comment: @Sofian Thank you very much for your response.